# AngularJS dynamically compiled directive inside ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have adopted a plunker from [Pete Bacon Darwin](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zMsNnpNfOFwExSqLj2I?p=preview) and have created a directive for input field validation. The directive works fine in static fields but does not function if found in ngRepeat statements.
What the directive does is after it finds it self on an input, it attaches a dynamically compiled template ($http.get from html file, the file itself contains another ngRepeat) just after the input element. The template contains typical angularJS validation code, but generated by ngRepeat and an error key, message dictionary. Unfortunately when the ngrepeat reruns (adding more input fields for example) the template does not seem to be recompiling (more specifically the $field item is undefined).

The code is quite large so I included it in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vdkPCCYfbsjquPXcDaRy)

Now this is the resulting dom from a static field:

```
    <input name="full_name" type="text" ng-model="vm.user.fullName" required="" ng-pattern="vm.fullNamePattern" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="30" 
data-cv-input-val data-required-error="Your first and last name is required." data-min-length-error="Minimum of two characters per name." 
data-max-length-error="The name is too long." data-pattern-error="Please use this format: Xx[space]Xx.">
<div class="form-fields__error-container ng-scope" ng-class="{'opacity--half': opacityHalf}" ng-show="($field.$dirty || $form.attempt) &amp;&amp; $field.$invalid" style="">
    <!-- ngRepeat: (key, error) in $field.$error -->
    <span ng-repeat="(key, error) in $field.$error" ng-show="error &amp;&amp; tooltipVisible" class="error-tooltip ng-scope ng-binding ng-hide">The name is too long.</span>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: (key, error) in $field.$error -->
    <span ng-repeat="(key, error) in $field.$error" ng-show="error &amp;&amp; tooltipVisible" class="error-tooltip ng-scope ng-binding ng-hide">Minimum of two characters per name.</span>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: (key, error) in $field.$error -->
    <span ng-repeat="(key, error) in $field.$error" ng-show="error &amp;&amp; tooltipVisible" class="error-tooltip ng-scope ng-binding ng-hide">Please use this format: Xx[space]Xx.</span>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: (key, error) in $field.$error -->
    <span ng-repeat="(key, error) in $field.$error" ng-show="error &amp;&amp; tooltipVisible" class="error-tooltip ng-scope ng-binding ng-hide">Your first and last name is required.</span>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: (key, error) in $field.$error -->
</div>
```

And this is a from a field generated by ng-repeat:

```
<span data-ng-repeat="email in vm.person.emails" ng-scope">
    <input type="email" ng-model="email.email" id="email-2" placeholder="Email" data-cv-input-val="">
    <div class="form-fields__error-container ng-scope ng-hide" ng-class="{'opacity--half': opacityHalf}" ng-show="($field.$dirty || $form.attempt) &amp;&amp; $field.$invalid" style="">
    <!-- ngRepeat: (key, error) in $field.$error -->
    </div><!-- end ngIf: $index > 0 -->
</span>
```

Comment: BTW I also tried creating a directive assigned to the ng-repeat that emmits a ng-repeat-done message on the scope and although the controller can catch it with scope.$on, the directive (inside the linking function) above cannot.